# How can I achieve animated app bar with tab bar(defaultTabController) sticky under it when scrolling down?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I want to show a transparent background appbar with (extendBodyBehindAppBar:true) initially. When I'm scrolling, the appbar should get background color and I have defaultTabController inside the body, the Tab Bar should get sticky under the appbar while scrolling.

I have attached the video link (Expected Output).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U3M-9cywy5Dn1V-7Xx7Pbx0Rg79fmTiw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share some code snippets, What you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried nested scroll view. but couldn't get the expected result.